# Запретить доступ к верхним директориям Python

Tags: python

Делаю небольшой файловый менеджер внутри сайта для выбора изображений (как в opencart, wordpress).

Не буду вдаваться в подробности, но есть представление, которое получая из `get`параметра `path` отображает содержимое директории (файлы, папки) '`media/path`'.

Т.е. допустим `path` из `ajax` запроса равен `catalog`. Значит я должен показать содержимое директории `something/media/catalog`. Т.е. выше `media` нельзя - там то, что не должен видеть пользователь.

Проблема в том, что `path` из `ajax` может быть, например, такой `catalog/../../../` и тогда отобразиться то, что не должно. Как запретить? Как проверить, является ли путь, которой пришел из запроса, подпутем `media`?

Comment: Попробовать через `os.path.normpath` получить нормальный путь? `print(os.path.normpath('something/media/catalog/../../../'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from os import path

ROOT_DIR = '/absolute/path/to/something/media'
ajax_path = 'catalog/../../../'

if ROOT_DIR in path.abspath(path.join(root_path, ajax_path)):
    # Подкаталог
else:
    # Показать хакеру обидный текст или даже похабную картинку
```

Comment: Спасибо, выручили!